# Optimizing left join select query of large data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to know if there is a faster or better way of handling the following situation:

I currently find myself struggling to optimize the execution time of a lengthy select query, where I need to make left joins for each unique field per record (basically pivoting the table). Is there a way to minimize this with a single join/pivot to reduce the time taken to retrieve data?

I need to make provision for 50 custom fields, which times out on 30000 odd records (this is with indexes on the relevant columns)

I would appreciate any help (that includes correcting the title as I'm not sure how to state it otherwise) Thanks in advance.

Below is code to setup a small example:

```
Create Table CustomField (
ID int identity (1,1) Not Null,
FieldName varchar(50) Not null,
FieldOrderNumber int Not Null);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomField] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomField] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

```
Create Table FieldValue (
ID int identity (1,1) Not Null,
CustomFieldID int Not Null,
PersonID int Not Null, 
FieldValue varchar(50));

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FieldValue ] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_FieldValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

```
Create Table Person (
ID int identity (1,1) Not Null,
PersonName varchar (50) Not Null);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

```
Insert into Person (PersonName)
Values ('Marc');

Insert into Person (PersonName)
Values ('John');

Insert into CustomField (FieldName, FieldOrderNumber)
Values ('BloodType',1);

Insert into CustomField (FieldName, FieldOrderNumber)
Values ('EyeColour',2);

Insert into FieldValue (CustomFieldID , PersonID, FieldValue)
Values (1,1, 'A+');

Insert into FieldValue (CustomFieldID , PersonID, FieldValue)
Values (1,2, 'O-');

Insert into FieldValue (CustomFieldID , PersonID, FieldValue)
Values (2,1, 'Blue');

Insert into FieldValue (CustomFieldID , PersonID, FieldValue)
Values (2,2, 'Hazel');



WITH ListFieldValues (FieldOrderNumber, FieldName, PersonID, FieldValue)
AS
(
SELECT cf.FieldOrderNumber, cf.FieldName, fv.PersonID, fv.FieldValue
FROM CustomField cf LEFT JOIN FieldValue fv ON cf.ID = fv.CustomFieldID
)


SELECT p.ID,
    p.PersonName,
    lvf.FieldValue AS Column1, --Bloodtype
    lvf2.FieldValue as Column2 --EyeColour    
FROM Person p 
LEFT JOIN ListFieldValues lvf ON p.ID = lvf.PersonID and lvf.FieldOrderNumber =1 
LEFT JOIN ListFieldValues lvf2 on p.ID = lvf2.PersonID and lvf2.FieldOrderNumber = 2
```

Comment: You need to add indexes on the columns you're joining on. Also, please tag the question with the DBMS you're using: MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: I already have index in place on the DB for the relevant tables in question.

Comment: You posted the `CREATE TABLE` statements, they don't mention any indexes. Post the index creation statements so we can see if you have the correct ones.

Comment: Indexes added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create indexes on identity columns. Then create indexes on Columns where you're joining. These tips will improve your execution time.

Comment: I added indexes to the post, there are indexes on the relevant tables question that I'm having trouble with